# typing environment inside tikz node with ConTeXt

Tags: tikz-pgf, context

I want to render some lines of code inside a tikz node:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\definetyping[code][bodyfont=small,escape={`,`}]

\starttext
\tikzset{
  code/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black}
}
\starttikzpicture[node distance=.7cm]
  \node[code] (g1) {
    \startcode
             i = 1
             t1 = 20
      iloop: if i > t1 goto iexit
    \stopcode
  };
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

Which renders:

[image]

As you can see, all line breaks are missing. I managed to enhance this by using paragraphs:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\definetyping[code][bodyfont=small,escape={`,`}]

\defineparagraphs[CodeNode][n=1]
\setupparagraphs[CodeNode][1][width=.5\textwidth]

\starttext
\tikzset{
  code/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black}
}
\starttikzpicture[node distance=.7cm]
  \node[code] (g1) {
    \startCodeNode
      \startcode
              i = 1
              t1 = 20
        iloop: if i > t1 goto iexit
      \stopcode
    \stopCodeNode
  };
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

This renders:

[image]

Which is more close to what I want, but I now needed to give a specific width. How can I create a node that automatically encloses the given code without giving a width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate the code in a `framed` environment. (Using [»Making a tight vertical fit« from the Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_text#Making_a_tight_vertical_fit))

```
\usemodule[tikz]

\defineframed
  [codeframed]
  [frame=no,
   width=fit,
   align=right,
   strut=no,
   offset=0pt]

\definetyping
  [code]
  [bodyfont=small,
   escape={`,`},
   before={\startframed[codeframed]},
   after={\stopframed}]

\starttext

\tikzset{
  code/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black}
}
\starttikzpicture[node distance=.7cm]
  \node[code] (g1) {
    \startcode
             i = 1
             t1 = 20
      iloop: if i > t1 goto iexit
    \stopcode
  };
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

The same can be achieved using `framedtext` which looks, in my opinion, a little bit cleaner than the `framed` solution.  (Thanks to [Hans for pointing out](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/087515.html) `location=none`)

```
\usemodule[tikz]

\defineframedtext
  [codeframed]
  [frame=no,
   width=fit,
   location=none,
   offset=0pt]

\definetyping
  [code]
  [bodyfont=small,
   escape={`,`},
   before={\startcodeframed},
   after={\stopcodeframed}]

\starttext

\tikzset{
  code/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black}
}
\starttikzpicture[node distance=.7cm]
  \node[code] (g1) {
    \startcode
             i = 1
             t1 = 20
      iloop: if i > t1 goto iexit
    \stopcode
  };
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

If the usage of TikZ is not compulsory, you might want to use `framedtext` alone.

```
\defineframedtext
  [codeframed]
  [autowidth=force,corner=round]

\definetyping
  [code]
  [bodyfont=small,
   escape={`,`},
   before={\startcodeframed},
   after={\stopcodeframed}]

\starttext

\startcode
  i = 1
  t1 = 20
  iloop: if i > t1 goto iexit
\stopcode

\stoptext
```

[image]